# Proof-verification: Show that there exists an exact sequence

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-verification, modules, exact-sequence

Let $R$ be a ring and let 
$$
M_1 \stackrel{f_1}{\hookrightarrow} M_2 \\
\alpha_1\downarrow \hspace{1cm} \downarrow \alpha_2 \\
N_1 \stackrel{f_2}{\hookrightarrow} N_2
$$
be a commutative diagram of $R$-modules in which the two horizontal maps are injective. I need to show that there exists an $R$-module $E$ and an exact sequence 
$$ \DeclareMathOperator{\coker}{coker}
0 \to \ker(\alpha_1) \to  \ker (\alpha_2) \to E \to \coker (\alpha_1) 
\to \coker(\alpha_2)
$$
of $R$-modules.

**What I have tried so far**: extending the diagram on the right with the projection maps $g_1 : M_2 \to \coker(f_1)$ and $g_2 : N_2 \to \coker(f_2)$, and the map $\alpha_3 : \coker(f_1) \to \coker(f_2) : \overline{x} \mapsto \overline{\alpha_2(x)}$ (which can be shown to be well-defined). Then we can use Snake's lemma to obtain an exact sequence 
$$
0 \to \ker(\alpha_1) \to \ker (\alpha_2) \to \ker(\alpha_3) \to \coker(\alpha_1) \to \coker (\alpha_2) \to \coker(\alpha_3) \to 0
$$
Hence if we take $E = \ker(\alpha_3)$ and just `cut-off' the last two elements of this exact sequence, we are done. Is this correct?

Comment: That is correct

Comment: Thank you for checking!